# Get relationship status of facebook friend from facebook graph api

Tags: ios, iphone, fb-graph

In my app i want to get relationship status of facebook friend. I am use this code for it

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                              parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,name,gender,is_verified,friends{id,gender,name,picture{url},relationship_status}",}
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Insert your code here
}];
```

Not get relationship status in my device.

I am get this status here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cgender%2Cis_verified%2Cfriends%7Bid%2Cgender%2Cname%2Cpicture%7Burl%7D%2Crelationship_status%2Cbio%7D&version=v2.5.

Can anyone please help me.